# Iterate all checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am having some difficulties when trying to iterate all checkbox and check if it is checked. Here is the code:

```
content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
content += "<tr><td><input class=\"pssLabel\" type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('pssLabel')\">Show Label</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td><div id=\"pss\"></div></td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"padding:5px;font-size:15px;color:black;\">Development Type</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input value='Commercial and Residential' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()' >Commercial and Residential</td><td><input value='Commercial' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()' >Commercial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input value='Heavy Vehicle Park' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Heavy Vehicle Park</td><td><input value='Hospital' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Hospital</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input value='Hotel' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Hotel</td><td><input value='Industrial' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Industrial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input value='Industrial-White' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Industrial-White</td><td><input value='Office' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS()'>Office</td></tr>";
```

Here is how I iterate all checkbox and perform checking:

```
function queryPSS() {
var type_filter = new Array();

//Iterate thru all checkbox
$(":checkbox").each(function(index, element) {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))       
    {
        type_filter.push($(this).val());            
    }
});

}
```

However, is there any way for me to skip the first checkbox (no matter checked or not) and check for other checkbox and store into array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right there in your `.each()` callback is the `index` argument which will let you test if it's the first checkbox or not.  You could also use a common class name on the checkboxes that you do want to iterate and just query on that class name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assigned pssLabel class to your first input, you can skip the check box with that class:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(index, element) {
    if($(this).hasClass('pssLabel')) return;

    if($(this).is(':checked'))       
    {
        type_filter.push($(this).val());            
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe exclude `.pssLabel` in the selector and not bother with the test?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple if condition like

```
if (index !== 0)
```

full code:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(index, element) {
    if (index !== 0) { //skip first checkbox
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        type_filter.push($(this).val());            
       }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:gt(0)`

```
$(":checkbox:gt(0)").each(function(index, element) {
```

`--->` https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: or:

`...each(function(index, element) { if (index == 0) return true;...`

Comment: Sure thanks. This method work as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can target only the checkboxes with class `pssCheckBox` as first one don't have it.

```
function queryPSS() {
    var type_filter = $("input.pssCheckBox:checked").map(function (index, element) {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

}
```

Also have a look at the use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score -1):

yes use `.map()` like up floor

```
var type_filter = $("input[name='instanceCheck']:checkbox:checked").map(function(index, element) {
        return this.value;
}).get();
```

this callback is sync function  each callback is async function