# Node.js Checkbox Iteration

Tags: mysql, node.js, checkbox, pug

How do I iterate through the checked checkboxes, without hard coding and checking each box one at a time. Kinda like this link, but with Node.js and not JavaScript
[Iterate all checkbox in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653072/iterate-all-checkbox-in-javascript):

So I'm attempting to display the contents of my database (using MySQL), but I don't want to hard code 'req.body.checkboxName' for every checkbox in case a new column is added onto a table (the checkboxes are each of the columns in a given table). So I need to find a way that will iterate through every checkbox in the webpage and see if it is checked. If it is then we'll add them together in a string and query for those columns. My code below is for the Node.js POST method (after hitting submit once the checkboxes are checked) and the other is my Pug/Jade code (the JavaScript Templating Engine that I use, sorry it isn't plain html).

In case you're confused how the Pug/Jade file runs initially, another GET method renders that Pug/Jade file with the column names; that GET method is basically the POST method below up until the '//Need help' line

Node.js

```
app.post('/GetTables', function(req, res){
    var columnsRequest =  'DESCRIBE ' + tableName;
    var columnsList = [];
    connection.query(columnsRequest, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err){
             throw err;
        }
        for (var index in results) {
            console.log(results[index].Field);
            columnsList.push(results[index].Field);
        }
    });


    //Need help, the next 5 or so lines are non-working ~psuedocode
    var checkedList = '';    
    req.body.CHECKBOXES.each(function(index, element){
        if(CHECKBOX.ischecked(){
            checkedList += CHECKBOX.name() + ', '
        }
    });


    var mysqlRequest =  'SELECT ' + checkedList + ' FROM ' + tableName;
    connection.query(mysqlRequest, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.render('webPage', {'columnstodisplay': results});
    });

});
```

Pug/Jade

```
form(method = 'POST', action = '/GetTables', id = 'tableform')
    fieldset
        each item in columns
            //this loop sets up the checkboxes for each of the columns
            p
                input(type="checkbox", name=item, value=item)
                span #{item}
                br
        input(type ='submit', value ='Submit')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for waiting a month to answer my own question. Below is the code that I have. Essentially what I did was when the submit button was clicked, it called a JavaScript function that sees which checkboxes are checked and creates two hidden elements; an array of checked checkboxes and the string to place in the MySQL query (the query asks for the columns/the checkboxes that were checked).

```
app.post('/GetTables', function(req, res){
    var columnsRequest =  'DESCRIBE ' + tableName;
    var columnsList = [];
    connection.query(columnsRequest, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err){
             throw err;
        }
        for (var index in results) {
            console.log(results[index].Field);
            columnsList.push(results[index].Field);
        }
    });     
    //changed the line below****
    var mysqlRequest =  'SELECT ' + req.body.checkboxNames + ' FROM ' + tableName;
    connection.query(mysqlRequest, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        //changed the line below********
        res.render('webPageName', {'columns': columnsList, 'rows': results, 'fields': fields, 'recheckboxes':req.body.checkboxArray});
    });

});
```

Pug/Jade

```
form(method = 'POST', action = '/GetTables', id = 'tableform')
    fieldset
        each item in columns
            //this loop sets up the checkboxes for each of the columns
            p
                input(type="checkbox", name=item, value=item)
                span #{item}
                br
        input(type ='submit', value ='Submit', onclick="sendCBs(document.thisForm, '/gettables')")

        script.
            function sendCBs(form, path, method) {
                var cbNames = '';
                var cbArray = [];
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
                    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                                cbNames += form.elements[i].value + ', ';
                                cbArray.push(form.elements[i].value);
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(count > 0){
                        cbNames = cbNames.replace(/,\s*$/, ""); //remove the last comma if 1 or more checkboxes selected
                    }
                    else{
                        return;
                    }

                    method = method || "POST";  //if not specified, method will be post
                    var inputform = document.createElement("form");
                    inputform.setAttribute("method", method);
                    inputform.setAttribute("action", path);

                    var hiddenField1 = createHiddenInput("checkboxNames", cbNames);
                    var hiddenField2 = createHiddenInput("checkboxArray", cbArray);

                    inputform.appendChild(hiddenField1);
                    inputform.appendChild(hiddenField2);

                    document.body.appendChild(inputform);
                    inputform.submit();
                }
```